# Pandas Merging User Logon and Logoff times

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am new to Pandas and I am trying to calculate screen time. Basically the time a user had the screen unlocked on a workstation. The data looks like the following:

```
    User    Action  ActionTime
0   User1   logon   1/1/2020 8:00
1   User1   lock    1/1/2020 12:00
2   User1   unlock  1/1/2020 13:00
3   User1   logoff  1/1/2020 16:00
```

Right now I am trying to merge logon actions (logon and unlock) and the logoff actions (logoff and lock) onto single lines with their timestamps. Example:

```
        Action_x ActionTime_x   Action_y    ActionTime_y
User                
User1   logon   1/1/2020 8:00   lock    1/1/2020 12:00
User1   unlock  1/1/2020 13:00  logoff  1/1/2020 16:00
```

To accomplish this i tried putting my logon and logoff actions into their own dataframe and then attempting to merge them together.

```
logon = df[df["Action"].isin(["logon","unlock"])]
logon.set_index("User", inplace= True)

logoff = df[df["Action"].isin(["logoff","lock"])]
logoff.set_index("User", inplace= True)

merged = pd.merge(logon, logoff, right_index=True, left_index=True)
```

What I get in my output is this:

```
        Action_x ActionTime_x   Action_y ActionTime_y
User                
User1   logon   1/1/2020 8:00   lock    1/1/2020 12:00
User1   logon   1/1/2020 8:00   logoff  1/1/2020 16:00
User1   unlock  1/1/2020 13:00  lock    1/1/2020 12:00
User1   unlock  1/1/2020 13:00  logoff  1/1/2020 16:00
```

Clearly I have much to learn about merging. Is this action possible with a merge or am I missing something.

Edit: in this example User is my index for the dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of *merge*, take another approach:

1. To get separate results for each user, group your DataFrame
   by *User*.
2. To each group of rows (for particular user) apply a function
   which:

   - Performs a second level grouping on *Action.isin(['logon', 'unlock'].cumsum()*.
     This way each row with *Action* of either *logon* or *unlock*
     starts a new group (actually composed of 2 rows, the second row
     in this pair is a row concerning either *lock* or *logoff*).
   - The result from each such group should contain:

     - *Login Action* - the *Action* from the first row,
     - *Start* - the *ActionTime* from the first row,
     - *Logoff Action* - the *Action* from the last row,
     - *Stop* the *ActionTime* from the last row.

The code to do it is:

1. Define the function to be applied to each group of rows
   for the current user:

   ```
   def act(grp):
       return grp.sort_values('ActionTime').groupby(grp.Action.isin(['logon', 'unlock'])
           .cumsum()).agg(**{'Login Action': ('Action', 'first'),
               'Start': ('ActionTime', 'first'), 'Logoff Action': ('Action', 'last'),
               'Stop': ('ActionTime', 'last')})
   ```

   In order to have spaces in column names I used *dictionary unpacking*.
2. Apply it to each group:

   ```
    result = df.groupby('User').apply(act).reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
   ```

   Additional element is to drop unnecessary index level.

To present a more instructive example, I created the source
DataFrame (for 2 users) as:

```
    User  Action          ActionTime
0  User1   logon 2020-01-01 08:00:00
1  User1    lock 2020-01-01 12:00:00
2  User1  unlock 2020-01-01 13:00:00
3  User1  logoff 2020-01-01 16:00:00
4  User2   logon 2020-01-01 08:15:00
5  User2    lock 2020-01-01 08:17:00
6  User2  unlock 2020-01-01 09:22:00
7  User2  logoff 2020-01-01 09:35:00
```

The result of my code is:

```
      Login Action               Start Logoff Action                Stop
User                                                                    
User1        logon 2020-01-01 08:00:00          lock 2020-01-01 12:00:00
User1       unlock 2020-01-01 13:00:00        logoff 2020-01-01 16:00:00
User2        logon 2020-01-01 08:15:00          lock 2020-01-01 08:17:00
User2       unlock 2020-01-01 09:22:00        logoff 2020-01-01 09:35:00
```

I assume that your *DataFrame* is sorted by *ActionTime*, either
globally or at least for each user (actually, sorted by *User* and
*ActionTime*, so I didn't include any sort.
If this condition is not met, add sort, e.g. in *act* function:

```
return grp.sort_values('ActionTime').groupby(...)
```

Comment: Thank you Valdi_Bo. This gives me alot to think about. Is there anyway to return strings to the result dataframe. Like if I wanted to pass on the sting from the Action column. So that I had columns of "User, Login Action, Start, Logoff Action, Stop"

Comment: I corrected my solution, to include also both "Action" columns.